# Access item that is destructured

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, clojurescript, ecmascript-next

In ClojureScript it is possible to store the original item to be destructured in a separate value. For example when calling the anonymous function below with the map `{:a "A" :b "B" :c 3 :d 4}` the keys `a` and `b` are destructured and the original map is stored in `m` using the `:as` operator.

```
((fn [{:keys [a b] :as m}]
   (println "a is" a)
   (println "b is" b)
   (println "m is" m))
  {:a "A" :b "B" :c 3 :d 4})

;; => a is A
;;    b is B
;;    m is {:a "A" :b "B" :c 3 :d 4}
;;    nil
```

Is a similar operation available in ECMAScript? E.g.,

```
(({ a, b }) => {
  console.log(`a = ${a}`);
  console.log(`b = ${b}`);
  console.log(`m = ${???}`);
})({ a: "A", b: "B", c: 3, d: 4 });
```

Or is it necessary to store the original item first in a variable and destructure later?

```
((m) => {
  const { a, b } = m;
  console.log(`a is ${a}`);
  console.log(`b is ${b}`);
  console.log(`m is ${m}`);
})({ a: "A", b: "B", c: 3, d: 4 });

;; => a is A
;;    b is B
;;    m is [Object object]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If original parameter is supposed to be accessed, it should be destructured to variables in function body:

```
(m) => {
  const { a, b } = m;
  ...
}
```

Even if it's not accessed, this style is beneficial because it allows to debug parameters in case of a problem, especially in native arrow functions where `arguments` is not available.